# How to create a Netbeans 7 project from an existing git repo?

Tags: git, netbeans, repository, project

I'd imagine there is a 'new project from repo' option somewhere but I can't find it. Is there more to it than this, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just clone the repo into your (newly created) netbeans project and then refresh (build) it.

Comment: Could you walk through the steps for that please for those of us who are brand new to Netbeans?

Comment: This way fails with message: "Specified destination already exists and is not an empty directory.". The only working way I use is via command line `git remote add origin {URL}` and if the `origin` already exists I use `git remote rm origin` and then continue adding.

Answer (score 27):

Use the **Team** menu, select "Git" > "Clone..."

Once the repo has been cloned into a local folder, NetBeans will give you the option to open the project.

Trying to create a project and then clone into it fails because the target folder is not completely empty.

Comment: there s no Team > Git > Clone :S i guess it depends on what u select or sth

Comment: Close all the projects or "deselect" them going to a "general window" (e.g. Services) and the option will appear

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

```
> git clone https://github.com/path/project
```

Then in NetBeans:
  File > New Project > choose a project type "...with Existing Sources" > "Next"
  select "Source Folder" (the folder you cloned into) and press "Finish"

Unfortunately, it seems that your project must already correspond to a project type that NetBeans already supports (eg. Java Application, HTML5/JS Application, etc). If it doesn't you probably won't get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

But if you want to use a **local git repository** (i.e. a repo that was alredy cloned from the git server e.g. by Eclipse) in Netbeans **without** cloning it from the server, you have to click on Team --> Git --> Clone and in the input field "Repository URL" type *file:///D:/your.local.git.repo/*. In the field "Clone into:" you have to specify the destination folder of the cloning.

This will "make a copy" of *D:/your.local.git.repo/* into the destination folder.
[image]